# How to sort and merge into an iterator two vectors of different structs based on a field?

Tags: rust

I need to draw two vectors of objects from back to front based on their distance, but these object are different structs that both have a field for its distance to the camera. How would I sort them to iterate from bigger to smaller distance?

Repro:

```
struct ItemA{
    distance: f32,
}

struct ItemB{
    distance: f32,
}

impl ItemA{
    fn draw_a(&self) -> {
println!("d: {}", self.distance);
    }
}

impl ItemB{
    fn draw_b(&self) -> {
println!("d: {}", self.distance);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec_a = vec![ItemA{distance: 1}, ItemA{distance:4}, ItemA{distance:10}];
    let vec_b = vec![ItemB{distance: 2}, ItemB{distance:6}, ItemB{distance:7}];
    
    // Should print in order d: 10(a), d: 7(b), d: 6(b), d: 4(a), d: 2(b), d: 1(a)

    }
}
```

Rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a1b58729f60fac8312a2fadc6663c633

Comment: You can use [trait objects](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd82eb5737ddec05d939126275be3478).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that makes use of an enum to create a type which can store both `ItemA` or `ItemB`. This is an alternative to boxing that does not rely on dynamic dispatch.

```
struct ItemA {
    distance: f32,
}

struct ItemB {
    distance: f32,
}

impl ItemA {
    fn draw_a(&self) {
        println!("d: {}(a)", self.distance);
    }
}

impl ItemB {
    fn draw_b(&self) {
        println!("d: {}(b)", self.distance);
    }
}

enum AB {
    A(ItemA),
    B(ItemB),
}

impl AB {
    fn dist(&self) -> f32 {
        match self {
            AB::A(a) => a.distance,
            AB::B(b) => b.distance,
        }
    }

    fn draw(&self) {
        match self {
            AB::A(a) => a.draw_a(),
            AB::B(b) => b.draw_b(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec_a = vec![
        ItemA { distance: 1.0 },
        ItemA { distance: 4.0 },
        ItemA { distance: 10.0 },
    ];
    let vec_b = vec![
        ItemB { distance: 2.0 },
        ItemB { distance: 6.0 },
        ItemB { distance: 7.0 },
    ];

    let mut all = vec_a.into_iter().map(|e| AB::A(e)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    all.extend(vec_b.into_iter().map(|e| AB::B(e)));

    all.sort_by(|a, b| {
        b.dist()
            .partial_cmp(&a.dist())
            .unwrap_or(std::cmp::Ordering::Equal)
    });

    // Should print in order d: 10(a), d: 7(b), d: 6(b), d: 4(a), d: 2(b), d: 1(a)
    for ab in all {
        ab.draw();
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
d: 10(a)
d: 7(b)
d: 6(b)
d: 4(a)
d: 2(b)
d: 1(a)
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3ab2f5009a4c183d7387598973d17b1)

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to sort both `Vec`, then explicitly having two indices starting at 0, and printing from either vector at each step, and advancing one index, like in the merge function from mergesort. It would work, but it would be verbose.

A an other solution would be to make a `Trait` with two methods: a `distance(&self) -> f32`, which would (in your case) just return `self.distance`, and  a `kind(&self) -> &str` which would return either `"a"` or `"b"`, and implement this trait for both `ItemA` and `ItemB`. In the end, you can create an homogeneous vector of `Box<dyn ThatTrait>` and sort that. I mention this solution because I can picture it being a viable solution for a renderer which can have several kind of objects on a scene, pretty much like how graphic toolkits do too in Rust. I think that, in the end, you'll want this solution if you have a medium to big project.

However, the simplest working solution for your example is probably just to extract the wanted information from each vector, and sort that:

```rust
fn main() {
    let vec_a = vec![ItemA {distance: 1.}, ItemA {distance: 4.}, ItemA {distance: 10.}];
    let vec_b = vec![ItemB {distance: 2.}, ItemB {distance: 6.}, ItemB {distance: 7.}];
    
    let mut vec_all = vec_a
        .iter()
        .map(|ItemA {distance}| distance)
        .chain(vec_b
            .iter()
            .map(|ItemB {distance}| distance)
        )
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    vec_all.sort_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap());
    for d in vec_all {
        println!("d: {}", d);
    }
}
```

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0337191a5ba779a770c581a4b4a91ac7).